# Shorten URL on flask server with mod_rewrite

Tags: url, mod-rewrite, flask

I want to shorten the URL for my flask based website from this:

```
mywebsite.com/cgi-bin/app/app.cgi/contact
```

to this:

```
mywebsite.com/contact
```

My .htaccess file includes the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /home/user/public_html/cgi-bin/app/app.cgi/$1 [L]
```

I'm running the website on a namecheap shared server if that makes a difference.
Thanks!